# How to dynamically add (or) insert values to data column in c#?

Tags: c#, datacolumn

I am iterating an excel file cell by cell. Each file has its own number of columns. Based on excel cell count, we are dynamically creating the columns to the data table. This part is working fine.

I will have to insert each cell value to the data column. How to dynamically add (or) insert values to data column in c#?

In an assumption, excel file has 2 rows and 3 colums

```
FirstName LastName Location
---------------------------
Albert     B         Miami
Jackson    C         Tampa
```

I will have to populate the data table / data column with these cell values. Foreach loop iteration is working fine and picking up each cell value. 
I am stuck on inserting each cell value to the data column / data row.

```
int iCellCount = 3;  // In this example, i am defining cell count = 3 as static value. In the real time, cell count is picked from the excel file.
var cellValue = string.Empty;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (ExcelReportCell excelCell in excelRow) // Iterating the excel cell row by row in the Excel Sheet
{
    cellValue = excelCell.GetText().ToString(); // cellValue is assigned dynamically through excel file cell by cell iteration logic
    for (int i = 1; i <= iCellCount; i++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add();
        // Expected to assign each column values
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say `// Expected to assign each column values` in your code, do you mean you want multiple rows in your DataTable that will represent your Excel file?

Comment: `DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();`  Then set the dr values for each cell, add it to the table: `dt.Rows.Add(dr);`

Comment: Based on iteration, cell values are assigned to columns. Where do the columns are assigned to the data row

Comment: Well, first you need to set the columns.  *Then*, you set the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all the columns (make your method independent of the column name, so no hard coded strings) and then add all the respective values.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
List<string> colList = new List<string>();

// Loop through column collection 
// Add all your columns to data table first
foreach (ExcelReportColumn eachColumn in excelColumn)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(eachColumn, typeof(string));
    colList.Add(eachColumn);
}

DataRow newRow;
int currentCol = 0;
// Then add your data rows
foreach (ExcelReportCell excelCell in excelRow)
{
    newRow = dt.NewRow();
    // Magic Method: You need to know the column name for the the current cell
    string columnName = colList[currentCol]; 
    newRow[columnName] = excelCell;
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
    currentCol++;
}
```

Comment: ,thank you.. i agree with you.. we need to add all the columns before assigning the records

Comment: If you have your solution from this answer please mark it as answered. If you need more info/help, fire away.

Comment: Column Names are not mapped to the data row and so , i am not able to get the columns in the data .. //Missing the Column Adding to the Row.
  dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

Comment: Not sure what you meant, but the idea is to have a strict order of column names indexed in an array. And use that while inserting rows.

Comment: Changed the answer a bit so it's easier to understand what I meant in above comment. Note - There might be easier way to do this with `Infragistics.dll` might want to read their documentation. But natively in c# the way mentioned in this answer should handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Here I assume your columns are already added. You can try this.

```
int iCellCount = 3;  // In this example, i am defining cell count = 3 as static value. In the real time, cell count is picked from the excel file.
var cellValue = string.Empty;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow row;  //Create a DataRow
foreach (ExcelReportCell excelCell in excelRow) // Iterating the excel cell row by row in the Excel Sheet
{
                    cellValue = excelCell.GetText().ToString(); // cellValue is assigned dynamically through excel file cell by cell iteration logic
                    for (int i = 1; i <= iCellCount; i++)
                    {
                        row = dt.NewRow();
                        row["Your_Column_Name_Here"] = cellValue;
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                     }
}
```

Comment: thank you Cujoey, i am working on the syntax . .. thanks for that ..!! there is some similarity between your syntax and alen's syntax.. helpful

Answer (score 0):

Since you cant use linq then here us another solution

First you must have a list of rows from the excel. so your first thing to do is generate the columns which is the first row in the excel file

```
var rowIndex =0;
forech (var row in excelrows){
DataRow dtRow= null;
var cellIndex = 0;
foreach (ExcelReportCell cell in row){
if (rowIndex ==0) // generate the columns
{
dt.Columns.Add(new ColumnData(cell.GetText().ToString()));
}else { // the columns has already been generated then generate the row
 dtRow = dtRow?? dt.NewRow();
 dtRow[cellIndex] = cell.GetText(); 
 }
cellIndex++;
}
if (dtRow != null)
  dt.Rows.Add(dtRow);

rowIndex ++;
}
```

Comment: thanks.. i am using the existing code logic which iterates cell by cell. Excel components are from Infragistics dll. I presume, we might not be able to use linq query .. in my scenario.. i tried, couldn't

Comment: Ok i have updated my answer, read it and try to understand the consept. I wrote this code in here so you may encounter some error when you past it in vs.

Comment: thank you alen, i am working on the syntax . .. thanks for that ..!!

Comment: Dont forget to mark this as an asnwer if it help you solve the problem