# How to dynamically add data columns to data row and then to the data table?

Tags: c#

Using C#; I am adding column names, column values to the data row and then adding the data rows to the data table dynamically.

In reference to my earlier post : [How to dynamically add (or) insert values to data column in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56655851/how-to-dynamically-add-or-insert-values-to-data-column-in-c)

Issue is , every time we add the data column .. it is adding as a new data row.
I will have to build the data columns and then add to the data row.

```
int i = 0;
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 

// for loop iterating through the cells in the excel -- Starts Here

if ( columnIndex <= iCellCount)
{ 
    dt.Columns.Add(excelRow.Cells[columnIndex].GetText().ToString(), typeof(string));
        dt.Columns[i].ColumnName = excelCell.Placeholder.ColumnName;
        i++;
}

DataRow dtRow;  
dtRow = dt.NewRow();

if (dt.Rows.Count <= excelRows.Count())
{
    dt.Rows.Add(dtRow);
}


// for loop iterating through the cells in the excel -- Ends Here
```

Comment: so make a method where you make te columns, and other for add rows, separe the logics

Comment: 1. You can't add column names to `DataRow`s - you add them to `DataTable`s. 2. You can't add data values to a `DataRow` before you have `DataColumn`s in the `DataTable`. 3. You can't add scratch built `DataRow`s to a `DataTable`. You must ask the `DataTable` for a new `DataRow` and then populate the values then add the `DataRow` to the `Rows` of the `DataTable`.

Comment: @NetMage , my challenge is adding rows of column records. when i iterate through rows of records, each column is added as new row of record. We are also adding the columns dynamically. Each row of record has to have 3 column of records

Comment: What do you mean by "rows of column records"? That makes no sense. What is the wrong with the code you have shown?

Comment: It is adding columns as new rows